# How to configure couchdb for global access?

Tags: macos, couchdb

I am running couchdb server on my laptop and want to access it from other host (android client)
I can see futon (couchdb web interface) locally through

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/
```

But I always get 404 for

```
http://"my_ip":5984/_utils/
```

Bind adress was manually changed to 0.0.0.from database configuration page and database's service was reloaded via laptop reboot

Please help me to discover, What I missed?

Comment: Could you post the HTTP response with headers? `curl -i http://"my_ip":5984/_utils/`

Comment: Sure I can.
For localhost request http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/ I got [this response](https://justpaste.it/yghz)
For request with my ip I got "Operation timed out" :(

Comment: Firewall issue? Are your ports open?

Comment: On Windows  8.1, I had  to add a rule to my firewall to get port 5984 to respond to requests from outside.

Comment: Alexis, thank you, now it all works :)
I didn't know that ports needed to be opened. I just lack in networking. 
You can make it as answer and I will approve it